# Xcode's Cocoa Touch Static Library for Objective Pascal cannot contain Arrays of Strings?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, freepascal

I have a large program made in Pascal which im trying to use as a compiled resource for an Objective-C project.

I've followed the steps from [here](http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/ObjP_Part10.html).

I can include some of my .pas old files into the project, but not the ones which have arrays of strings.

This doesn't mean the compiler can't read these files containing array of strings, in fact it creates the resource file correctly. However, when testing the resource file within an Objective-C project it crashes because of an i386 incompatibility issue. One of the files I'm trying to include has arrays of string, if I erase these arrays won't have any problem to use my resource. Can anybody tell me what is going on? Are there any other issues I'll also get instead from the array of string incompatibility.

Comment: Maybe the internal resource system  doesn't get properly initialized in library form.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more specific than "it crashes because of an i386 incompatibility issue" if you want to get useful help. The best way is to file a bug report at bugs.freepascal.org with a fully compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

To answer Marco's comment (I can't add comments because I don't have a stackoverflow account): the RTL always gets automatically initialized when using libraries on Mac OS X, even regardless of whether you use a static or a dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using *free pascal* with *Objective-C* without problems for *iPad/iPhone*.

What compile switches are you using? Here are mine for simulator:

```
/usr/local/bin/ppc386 -n -l -viwn -a -s -vbr \
-Scghi -Sh  \
-Xs  -g \
-FE. -Mmacpas -ghlttt \
-gw2 -O- \
-CRriot -Cr- -Mobjfpc \
-Fl/Xcode3.2.5/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib \
-Fi"some/file.pas" \
-Fi"some/dir/*" \
-Fu"anoter/dir" \
```

then move all .s to some target specific library search path like:

```
cp -v *.s "$/some/dir/your_app/build/your_app.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/your_app.build/DerivedSources-normal/i386/"
```

---

If nothing helps you can try to use *TStringList* instead of *Array of Strings*.